# In UML, can I have two sets of relationships between two classes?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Given the following situation:

> RQ1: A flight can only be carried out by one plane
>
> RQ2: A plane can be assigned to zero or more flights

So I have a class called **Flight** and a class called **Plane**.

I don't know if I'm over-thinking the relationship between **Flight** and **Plane** though.

So for RQ1, you'd have an association between Flight and Plane, and the multiplicity would be `Flight [1] ------ Plane [1]`

But then RQ2 comes along and I need an association between Flight and Plane but how do I manage the multiplicities? I think it would be `Flight [0...*] ------ Plane [1]`

[Problem is, doing that creates two classes and two association lines and 2 pairs of/4 individual multiplicity values which doesn't sound right either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL5AU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Imagine a self relation from `Person` to self. One would be `Father` and one would be `Mother` (just forget for a moment that this might be different since a not so far past). So you can have as many relations between two classes as needed.

If you use role names, the situation will clear up. So the association for RQ2 would be named `assignedFlights`. The `carriedOutFlight` role from RQ1 could also be an index into the `assignedFlights` (as implementation variant). But of course it can be a different association as well.